# How to remove message payload on Mule?

Tags: jms, mule, payload

I want to send a message to a Queue using the JMS Component. However, I don't want to send the payload message, but just a simple String with the server date time, using the MEL expression #[server.dateTime].

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Sounds like you want to replace the payload for that String, not remove it entirely. In that case you should use a ```set-payload``` component before the JMS outbound endpoint. HTH.

Comment: But I don't want to loose my payload. I just don't want to use the payload in my jms message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your JMS Component inside an Async Component, you will get a clone of the original payload. From this point you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Mule Enricher is another way to get this work done without disturbing the current payload..
Just put set payload with server.dateTime and send it to JMS outbound inside an Enricher .. it will work without disturbing or loosing the actual payload
Reference :- https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Message+Enricher
 and
[Mule Enrichment: enrich xml payload with http endpoint response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22059055/mule-enrichment-enrich-xml-payload-with-http-endpoint-response)

Pls note : if you use multiple message processor inside an Enricher, you need to put inside `<processor-chain/>`